# Passing useState update function to child causes undefined function error

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Using expo and react-native I have created a screen called `MainStateScreen` this screen essentially has two direct children called `OptionsComponent` and `NavigationButton`. `OptionsComponent` has multiple children that when modified, update the state of the `MainStateScreen` so we can pass that as a prop to the next screen with the `NavigationButton`. That's how it's supposed to work at least.

Instead, when I try to modify the `OptionsComponent`'s children and use `MainStateScreen`'s update function I get the following error.

Here is pseudo-code of my component composition:

**MainStateScreen.js**

```js
const defaultOptionsObject = [
    {
        name: '',
        value: 1,
        count: 0,
    },
    {
        name: '',
        value: 8,
        count: 0,
    },
    {
        name: '',
        value: 20,
        count: 0,
    },
    {
        name: '',
        value: 25,
        count: 0,
    },
    {
        name: '',
        value: 30,
        count: 0,
    },
    {
        name: '',
        value: 32,
        count: 0,
    },
    {
        name: '',
        value: 100,
        count: 0,
    },
]

const MainStateScreen = () => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState(defaultOptionsObject)

    return (
        <View>
            <ScrollView>
                <OptionsComponent options={options} setOptions={setOptions} />
            </ScrollView>
            <NavigationButton onPress={() => navigation.push('OtherScreen', { options })} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

**OptionsComponent.js**

```js
const SingleOptionComponent = ({ index, option, options, setOptions }) => {
    const [stateOption, setStateOption] = useState({ ...option })

    const updateCount = val => {
        const tempOption = { ...stateOption }
        if (val) {
            tempOption.count += 1
        } else if (tempOption.count !== 0) {
            tempOption.count -= 1
        }
        setStateOption(tempOption)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const tempOptions = [ ...options ]
        tempOptions[index] = { ...stateOption }
        setOptions(tempOptions) // Commenting this out removes the error.
    }, [stateOption])

    const AddSubtractButton = () => {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => updateCount(true)}>
                    <Text>Add</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => updateCount(false)}>
                    <Text>Subtract</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <ListItem rightElement={AddSubtractButton} />
    )
}

const OptionsComponent = ({ options, setOptions }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            {options.map((option, index) => {
                return (
                    <SingleOptionComponent
                        key={`${option?.value}-${index}`}
                        index={index}
                        option={option}
                        options={options}
                        setOptions={setOptions}
                    />
                )
            })}
        <View/>
    )
}
```

The exact error is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...options.map...')

This error is located at:
    in OptionsComponent (at MainStateScreen.js)
```

BUT when I `console.log` the `setOptions` function in the `useEffect` of `SingleOptionComponent`, `Function setOptions` is printed in the console.

If I remove the `setOptions(tempOptions)` call from the `useEffect` inside the `SingleOptionComponent` the error goes away but I need something like that to accomplish the pass up to the parent and over to the `NavigationButton`.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: what does your ```defaultOptionsObject``` look like?

Comment: @SKeney My apologies. I added it to the question.

Comment: Could it be the typo `usestate` or was that just when you were posting?

Comment: @SKeney It was a typo in the question. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 0):

A couple things I would suggest that may solve the issue without re-creating it on my machine.  Try adding `setOptions` to the `useEffect` dependency array.  Maybe for some reason it isn't getting an updated setOptions as it is passed down to the grandchild component.  You also should pass in `options` to it as your effect does dependent on when that value changes.

If that doesn't work try using spread operator `setOptions({ ... tempOptions})`.

If that doesn't work I would suggest handling the setOptions inside the uppermost component and instead passing a callback down to the grandchild rather than the `setOptions` function.  That callback and get the `option` pressed in the parent and then update it appropriately based off `option._id` (I would supply a unique _id to each option rather than dynamically calculating it just to be able to do the above.). Also makes code easier to understand what is going on as the parent will handle it's own state that it needs and setting it appropriately.

Comment: The effect is purposefully only dependent on the `option` (singular) as we only want the side effect to run when the singular option is updated. If I mark `options` AND `setOptions` dependency it would create an infinite loop. I've tried passing a callback function down instead, but I came up with the same error as indicated above. I haven't tried it with a conjunction of the two -- callback and id -- yet though, so I'll try that out. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't tried the spread or `setOptions` dependency though, so that's next as well. I'll keep you informed.